# ANN Term by best of the resulting minima

Tags: neural-networks

Faraway (1998) stated that ANN model is refitting 50 times from different random starting points and taking the best of resulting minima.

Can anyone explain the Faraway statement.

Comment: @itdxer it is not that he take the average of the output? and one more. if we cannot comapre the output because of the output not availabe, how do we know it is the bess ann model?

Comment: Since network has been refitted 50 times then output is available, because network was trained based on some data. Any network's training based on some error function minimizations. So you should be able to have some value that summarize network's prediction quality.

Comment: @itdxer did you have any suitbale notes that i can used to learn ann

Comment: What ann do you mean? That one that has been mentioned in the paper?

Comment: i want to learn how to analyze ann and choose the best model for ann..

Comment: You can select best model with Hyperparameter optimization algorithms. Check this article http://neupy.com/2016/12/17/hyperparameter_optimization_for_neural_networks.html

Answer (score 1):

Network has been trained 50 times with different weight values. After the 50 trainings the best result has been chosen.